# Real time notification in Silverlight

Tags: wcf, silverlight, mvvm, notifications

I'm working on some project, that is server-client silverlight application. What need to know is, how to implement a real time notification function in Silverlight? Here is the scenario, There is a table in database named notification, I need to display data from that table on the view. How could I do this? This notification system is much more like Facebook notifications.
Best regards.

Comment: You could use timer in silverlight to update messages dynamically, or go with Xmpp messages

Comment: Use SignalR for real time communications. However there is NOTHING real time about databases.

Comment: why dont you use Socket over here

Comment: @Aron is correct in with the statement "there is NOTHING real time about databases". However there is nothing real time about signalr when using silverlight either (http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/supported-platforms) You will get SSE or longpolling! And even if you do not use silverlight you will still ned win8+ and .NET4.5 to have a chance to get real time... I would look at other frameworks!

Answer (score 0):

SignalR is a good way forward, however in your case you may find query notifications are a better option. see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130764.aspx

Comment: SignalR is great. But in my case I still can do it with Push Data, Thank you. Hope to start a project with SignalR.